# How to build large applications with Active Record pattern?

Tags: activerecord

Recently I saw an inspiring quote:

> The secret to building large apps is never build large apps. Break
>   your applications into small pieces. Then, assemble those testable,
>   bite-sized pieces into your big application.

Is seems really great so I want to follow it.
But then I found because I'm using Active Record pattern provided by the framework, so every pieces in the business logic is tightly coupled with the active record and database schema.

This is means no matter what 'small piece' you are building, it has dependency on your active record entity. I feel that makes it not stand-alone enough.

How should I deal with it?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think "Tightly Coupled" and "Scalable" really fit well in the same sentence. ;-)

Comment: That's kind of what I was thinking.  Coupling and scalability are orthogonal concerns.

Comment: But I feel that high coupling between different components decreases scalability ... doesn't it? And Active Record makes every pieces in the business logic tightly coupled with the active record and database schema.